# How to open a new page after initial greeting?

Tags: vue.js

I display 5 different greetings on a website and after they have all been shown once I want to open the actual website. I am not sure how to do this. Here is the part where I update the 5 greetings:

```
methods: {
    startGreetingCycle() {
      const intervalDuration = 1200 / this.hellos.length;
      let currentIndex = 0;

      const displayNextGreeting = () => {
        if (currentIndex < this.hellos.length) {
          this.currentIndex = currentIndex;
          currentIndex++;
          setTimeout(displayNextGreeting, intervalDuration);
        } else {
          // All greetings have been shown, navigate to the actual website
          this.$router.push({ name: "Home" });
        }
      };

      displayNextGreeting();
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.startGreetingCycle();
  },
```

Can anyone help me out as I am very new to vue

Comment: To navigate to a new page with Vue Router you use `this.$router.push()` just like you're doing.  If your code isn't working right you'll need to provide more information than just the fact it's not working. What is the error or unexpected behavior you see when you run your code? We can't run your app to figure it out on our own so you'll need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77253427/edit) your question and provide that information.